# Javascript find and replace string within substring not using jquery

Tags: javascript

Hi can someone convert this jquery in to plain javascript?

```
$("body *").each(function () { 
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\[br\]/\g,'<br/>')); 
});
```

What it does is, it finds all [br] and then replace it with `<br/>`

The code above works perfectly in chrome but not in mozilla and IE so i need to execute it in plain javascript. many thanks to all!

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this in the first place? O_o

Comment: jQuery iexists to make cross-browser development easier. There is another problem somewhere.

Comment: jQuery exists to help newbies in making errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you had an illegal character in your regular expression.

This works: `$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\[br\]/g,'<br/>'));`

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tqksm/

Comment: this is what i like about stackoverflow.. so many answers in less than 10 minutes.. you guys rock!!.. thanks

Comment: @frank that's nice to hear, but what is the point of what you're doing in the first place? From where I'm standing, this looks completely pointless. What's the idea behind it?

Comment: in my web application, if I see these characters { } ; \n. i replaced it with [br] when it is saved in the database, so that when I print it in my web site it is replaced by the break line tag in html. That's it. Thanks

Comment: @frank - why dont you just replace those characters with `<br/>` before saving the to database. Saves some pretty intensive client-side work when displaying the data.

Comment: Oh yeah I remember, the web container replaces this characters with the &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Now change `body *` to `body`.

Comment: @SomeGuy - what? Why would you want to `each` over the single `body` element? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Jamiec and why would you want to mess with every element if body contains them all?

Comment: Ah I see, either way doing a client side replace like that is not a great idea.

Comment: I'd say unacceptable and will not be able to sleep tonight knowing something like that exists somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
window.onload=function(){
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( /\[br\]/g,'<br/>');
}
```

ps. In your code, there is a bug: instead of `/\[br\]/\g` should be `/\[br\]/g`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not jQuery. You have first to take a reference to the current html content, then apply the replace and finally inject the new html:

```
$("body *").each(function () { 
    var $this = $(this);
    var html = $this.html();
    $this.html(html.replace(/\[br\]/\g,'<br/>')); 
});
```

Comment: This is the same as the OP code. You've just split it out over more lines

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing the point here...rewriting it in plain Javascript is likely to only make it worse for you. One of jQuery's purposes is to take away all the pain that comes while writing Javascript that must work on all browser. So...I think you'd be best off if you start looking for an alternative approach on your jQuery code instead of rewriting it to plain Javascript.